# How to force widget be as wide as the width of the column

Tags: flutter, dart

The width of Container should be dynamic based on the Text widget width. The container should be as wide as the text, some thing like the image.

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Text("asdasd"),
    Container(color: Colors.white, height: 5),
  ],
);
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap it in Expanded widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the Column with `IntrinsicWidth`(little expensive).

```dart
IntrinsicWidth(
  child:Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Text("asdasd"),
      Container(color: Colors.white, height: 5),
    ],
 ))
```